# Why is this a SQL syntax error?

Tags: mysql, perl

I have this query in Perl:

```
my $pkg="%";
my $sql = "SELECT pid, CAST(pid as UNSIGNED) AS l FROM xmld ORDER BY l WHERE pkg LIKE ?";
my $files_ref = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref($sql, undef, $pkg);
```

It crashes with:

> DBD::mysql::db selectcol_arrayref failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pkg LIKE '%'' at line 1 at ...

I have been looking at this statement for hours, tried various things, but no luck.
Where is that extra single quote coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: `order by` goes after the `where` clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`order by` goes after the `where`:

```
SELECT pid, CAST(pid as UNSIGNED) AS l
FROM xmld
WHERE pkg LIKE ?
ORDER BY l;
```